# compare letter grades as numbers in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to show growth in comparing letter grade levels. I've been trying to find a way to use the letters to represent numbers (a=1, b=2, c=3, etc) and then subtract one letter grade from another (ex. H-F=2 Levels). I've tried using lookup and if functions but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Exactly what formulas have you tried? What data do you have in your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

Use code:

```
=CODE(UPPER("H")) - CODE(UPPER("F"))
```

You can replace the letters with cell references:

```
=CODE(UPPER(A1)) - CODE(UPPER(A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Super clever approach!